# Serve file as a download with Silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

My controller is basic

```
$app->get('/files/{type}', function ($type) use ($app) {

    $path = __DIR__ . "/../files/$type";

    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        $app->abort(404, "Ce fichier n'existe pas.");
    }

    return $app
        ->sendFile($path)
    ;
})->bind('getfile');
```

According to this [doc](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#sending-a-file) it works. When I call a correct URL, the file is open on the current window.

But I don't want to open the file in the browser, I want to open the dialog box to just save the file.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the "content-disposition" header to `attachment`.

E.g.:

```
return $app
    ->sendFile($path)
    ->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
basename($path));
```

Don't forget to add this at the top of your file:

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;
```

... so PHP knows what `ResponseHeaderBag` is, and the autoloader is able to find it.

[Linky](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html#method_setContentDisposition) to docs.

Comment: with a header("Content-Disposition:attachment;"); before the return, it works, but it is php brut...

Comment: Indeed... It's better with the use clause ^^ thanks @yivi I don't understand why silex doesn't give me an error

Comment: You didn't get an error because use of an undefined class is a "FATAL" error, the interpreter dies immediately. Almost assuredly you did have an error in your log. Sorry I forgot about the `use` statement. My IDE handles that stuff for me and I tend to forget. :) (A proper IDE should have warned you about the undefined class as well)